# Relatorio com Jasperreports retornando tabela pdf em branco

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, pdf, jasper-reports

Bom dia, tenho um sistema em javaEE PrimeFaces e Jsf, criei os relatórios com Jasperreports, estava tudo funcionado, mas apos uma atualização da Instancia linux ec2 AWS, os relatórios estão retornado as tabelas em PDF sem dados só as grid, o intrigante é que se rodo o WAR a partir de um contener local usando o dB da nuvem, gera o relatório certinho, quando uso o mesmo war na maquina da nuvem os relatórios retornam em branco, vem as linhas e colunas de acordo com a quantidade de dados que seria exibido, mas em branco.

Comment: Pelas informações que você passou acredito ser um problema relacionado as fontes. Veja se as fontes usadas pelo relatório estão disponíveis no servidor. 
Para não ficar dependente das fontes instaladas no servidor use o fonts extension do jasper, gere um jar contendo as fontes usadas pelos relatórios e coloque no build path da aplicação. Este link explica como fazer este procedimento: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension

Comment: Era isso mesmo, problema resolvido, valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se as fontes usadas pelo relatório estão disponíveis no servidor.
Para não ficar dependente das fontes disponíveis no servidor você pode usar o fontes extension do jasper e gerar um jar contendo as fontes usadas pelos relatórios, colocando o mesmo no build path da aplicação.
Para maiores instruções sobre como fazer isso siga este [link: community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)